# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't indent C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, indentation

Does anyone knows why Visual Studio 2010 does not indent C code and how may I make it indent automatically, *i.e.* while I type (I already know the keyboard shortcuts) the C code?

Answer (score 1):

Check Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Tabs->Indenting ？

Comment: `Smart` is selected...what does it means?

Comment: Smart is the default setting, which means that indenting should work well. While in your case, I don't why it doesn't work, maybe something else went wrong. Sorry I can't help you more.